# Twitter Typeahead Searching Comma Separated Values

Tags: javascript, json, csv, split, typeahead.js

I'm using [typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) v0.11.1, it all appears to be working apart form one thing.

I am searching a JSON dataset, a snippet of this can be seen below;

```
[
  {
    "last_name": "Jo",
    "first_name": "Smith",
    "location": "Plum,Newton"
  },
  {
    "last_name": "Sara",
    "first_name": "Gates",
    "location": "Bread"
  }
]
```

The issue I'm having is with the `location` values. If the `location` contains a comma seperated list of values, only the first one is searchable / discoverable.

These are the results of some searches;

- Searching for `plu`  > finds `Plum,Newton`
- Searching for `new` > `no results found`

Do I need some sor of custom function the splits the comma seperated values? I've never seen this done before but I know it's possible to [override the source](http://tatiyants.com/how-to-use-json-objects-with-twitter-bootstrap-typeahead/) option using a function - not sure if this is what I need or not?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/5zmyzT

I went ahead and wrote a fiddle that parses the location, and allows typeahead to work against comma separated values.

Overriding the source options will not work, as we need to split our values.

```
https://dotnetfiddle.net/5zmyzT
```